# Different behaviour Anaconda prompt vs Command prompt

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-line, conda

I am trying to create a tensorflow environment that I can use within VSCode.

I started by following the guide [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/), and so i ran the commands in my anaconda prompt:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

When I then access this environment in my anaconda prompt I can import tensorflow successfully.

If I try to do the equivalent using the command prompt, after renaming the .exe and adding it to the PATH variables (so I can access from the command line) I get an import error:

```
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
```

I have no idea why I am getting different behaviours. Perhaps it is because I am changing the .exe name (I tried this before and after activating my env).

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

You installed tensorflow in conda environment, so other packages or anything required by tensorflow would be installed in conda environment automatically. If you just rename .exe and use it outside the conda environment, tensorflow cannot import what it requires(In your error case it's numpy C-extensions).

My advice is installing tensorflow again outside conda environment if you want to use it without anaconda prompt.